# WCF callback invokes all clients

Tags: c#, wcf, callback, client-server

I am using wsdualhttpbinding to connect the client and WCF Service. My client likes to invoke a long running request and wanted a periodic status update, hence I have choosen callbackcontracts. that worked fine. However It publishes for all clients who have just been loaded and has not requested that operation.

Is it possible to direct the callbacks to the requestor alone, though all clients are loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an answer from this forum. Sharing this.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/c0fce1de-9793-48fa-8e4d-329297ac54d3